# Diagnosing LAN slowdowns

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ethernet, lan

I'm having trouble with a random network slow-downs, and I'm trying to figure how to go about diagnosing it.

Our system is comprised of 4 NVIDIA AGX Xaviers and 1 NVIDIA AGX Orin hooked up to a GigaBlox Gigabit switch (we've tried other switches and still had problems). The Xaviers are running Ubuntu 18.04 and the Orin is running Ubuntu 20.04. Most of the traffic is data from the Xaviers flowing to the Orin.

The problem is that randomly one of the Xaviers network connection will slow to a crawl. Pinging it then will have up to a 0.5sec delay. 3 of the Xaviers will be running fine. It just affects one system at a time. It normally goes away after a few minutes, and network speed returns to normal, but we need to prevent this from happening in the first place.

Basically, my question is: how could I start going about diagnosing what causes this? Are there certain tests than can be ran? Right now we're not sure if this caused by driver problems or hardware.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: t normally goes away after a few minutes, and network speed returns to normal,     ........   Try updating router firmware and restart routers.  Update the workstation network card drivers also.

Comment: Hey, John. Thanks for the reply! There's no router involved here. This is a LAN with just the 5 machines connected to the switch. Updating the network drivers is something I'll look into though.

Comment: In addition to drivers try updating the switch firmware.

Comment: What makes you believe it's just a network problem? I'd start by convincing myself that it's not just that each unit is slowing down in general periodically, like from some resource contention or thermal throttling. Then I'd take a packet trace to look at what's going on on the network. I'd also look for patterns in the syslogs or other logs to see if anything in the logs corresponds to the slowdown periods. Have you been running the usual Unix or Linux system performance monitoring tools? I feel like you should edit your Question to tell is what you've already tried and eliminated.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like it could be an Access Control Lists and IP Fragments. Your organization admin ought to have created an ACL Rules Flowchart. QOS. Hardware is inadequate. I worked with large-scale networks 14 years ago, now retired so take what I say with a grain of worms.

Comment: any evidence for this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).